# map action creator to props react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Problem statement: I have a class component in which I am trying to dispatch an action on click of a button.

Here is what the react class code looks like:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        // function that I want to call
        handlerFunction(value){
        dispatch(
            // action creator
          addProduct(value)
        )
      }

    }
  }

class Test extends Component {

    state = {value: "Hello World"}
    render() { 
        return ( 
            <div>
                <button onClick={()=>{this.handlerFunction(this.state.value)}}>Push me</button>
            </div>
         );
    }
}
```

When I click on the button, I get the following error

`TypeError: this.handlerFunction is not a function`

Can anybody help me with why thats happening?

EDIT: I have used connect - importing it at the beginning of the file and doing `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Test)` at the end

Comment: You need to use `connect` for connect Test component to mapDispatchToProps: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start#connect

Comment: Of course I used connect. I abstracted that out so that the question is focused on the problem I have. Guess I shouldve mentioned that in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very difficult to provide complete example of react-redux as so many files you need to add to include redux in your project. But I mentioned here only basic example where you must be clear on action reducer to implement redux.

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react';
import {connect, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import * as ServiceActions from './actions/service.actions';
import withReducer from 'app/store/withReducer';
import reducer from './reducers/service.reducer'
import {bindActionCreators} from "redux";

function TestDispatch(props) {
    const {
        handlerFunction
    } = props;

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {
                handlerFunction('Khabir');
            }}>Push me
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
            handlerFunction: ServiceActions.addProduct()
        },
        dispatch);
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(withReducer('service', reducer)(TestDispatch));
```